# Using AFnetworking to save mp4

Tags: objective-c, video, afnetworking, mp4

I've been using AFnetworking to download a video from a remote server. It works great except for the fact it downloads the file as data rather than the original format (in this case mp4).

Is there a way to set AFnetworking to download the file as an mp4? when it comes to playback it seems like a waste of time and resources to convert the data file back into mp4 each time the video is played.

My current code for gaining the file is below:

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[URL url]]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
initWithRequest:request];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[URL title]];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
        URL.videolocal = @"YES";
        [self saveToCoreData]; // video is not saved in core data, only a reference 

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    [operation start];
```

Comment: Are you sure remote server allows you to download files? Is it file at all, or maybe just a stream?

Comment: This code will save the raw data received from the server. If the data coming from the server is not in MP4 format, then you will need to transcode it to MP4 to save it as such (non-trivial).  If the data coming from the server *is* in MP4 format, then all you need to do is give the local file a `.mp4` extension and you should be good to go. Transcoding video will be well beyond the scope of AFNetworking's capabilities.

Comment: Thanks guys. I forgot to add the extension on! ipmcc, if you want to put your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

If the data coming from the server is already in MP4 format, then just name the file with a `.mp4` suffix.